Can you help me with my Node-Red Flow that
[mqtt-broker:HiveMQ] Connection failed to broker: mqtt://mqtt-dashboard.com:8884


I try restarting my node-red
Configuring my MQTT In node with the exact host, i.e.:



I still get the exact same error message in the terminal.

The configuration is not the same.
You have enabled SSL in the first image, but not in Node-RED. Tick the "use TLS" checkbox.
